# How are filters for polyphase decimation like?

Tags: filters, decimation

I know in naive decimation the signal should filtered by a low-pass filter with cutoff frequency equals to Nyquist rate.I don't know how the filter banks like for polyphase decimation. Are them still low-pass filters? and what are their cutoff frequency.